# Resizing (reducing) in Photoshop cuts into shapes

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, shapes, resize

I'm not sure how well the title is worded, but I'll explain better here. So I've got a .psd with some shapes (rasterized) and it's 12000x8400 (300dpi). I want to resize it too 800x560 but when I do, part of (or all, depending on the size) the shapes simply get bits cut out of them. Here's what I mean:

[image: hearts]

You'll notice the two hearts on the right are missing some chunks. Depending on the size I pick, the missing chunks can vary by size, can affect only one or all of the hearts, and can even change location (they could also be missing from the right or from the top). At 800x560 (which is what I want) just the two hearts on the right are affected.

All the hearts and light grey background are different layers and the same thing happens even when selecting all of them and choosing Free Transform to reduce their size. I know I could just merge them, but I can't because I've actually animated them (they go up and back down like in those bubbles you see on Messenger when someone's typing a message). I've tried every resampling method without any luck.

This has happened to me before, but simply zooming to 100% before resizing seemed to do the trick, but not this time, it would seem. Does anyone please have any idea how I can resize the whole thing without merging layers or losing parts of the hearts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on the Adobe forums just helped me fix this. Turns out I needed to go into Preferences -> Performance -> check Legacy Compositioning.